# Ubuntu 12.04.3 takes too long to mount usb 3.0 ntfs hard drive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, hardware-enablement-stack

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04.2 kernel 3.5.0-39 to 12.04.3 kernel 3.8.0-29 (raring kernel). Here is the problem: when I connect the usb 3.0 NTFS hard drive to my system, it takes about 5-7 min to mount the hard drive successfully! The usb 3.0 NTFS hard drive works well with ubuntu 12.04.2 kernel 3.5.0-39 and windows 8 (dual boot).

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 125f:a21a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c058 Logitech, Inc. M115 Mouse
```

dmesg | tail -n 50:

```
[ 2110.871454] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2110.890464] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2110.891863] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2110.891874] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2142.823966] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2142.842895] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2142.844277] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2142.844288] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2174.776259] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2174.795360] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2174.796794] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2174.796805] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2175.677168] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[ 2175.677180] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2206.728759] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2206.747804] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2206.749238] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2206.749250] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2238.681134] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2238.700144] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2238.701552] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2238.701563] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2270.633590] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2270.652574] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2270.653947] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2270.653958] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2302.586048] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2302.605016] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2302.606406] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2302.606417] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2303.853319]  sdc: sdc1
[ 2303.856211] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[ 2303.856214] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2334.538275] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2334.553109] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2334.554479] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2334.554481] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2366.490863] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2366.509769] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2366.511152] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2366.511183] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2398.443073] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2398.457795] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2398.459303] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2398.459309] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2430.395719] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2430.414627] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[ 2430.415988] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad8780
[ 2430.415997] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880147ad87c0
[ 2431.294666] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by downgrading the kernel from 3.8.0-29 to 3.8.0-27.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue also for some FAT32-USB drives - don't think it depends on filesystem, but on drive manufacturer.

Anyway, you can also (instead of downgrading) upgrade to 3.8.0-30 that also helps.